# How to download multiple Google Drive photos from URLs?

Tags: google-drive

I was sent about 500 Google Drive picture files and need a way to download them. The URLs send me to the Google Drive for each individual picture. Is there a way to download them without having to go to each page and hitting download manually?

I have tried to convert the links to the following: `http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=`, but can't seem to get a Download manager to download it [GetRight].

Comment: So the photos are in fact on someones Google Drive account? And they want to share these files with you? Again, it's the same idea. What do you mean by `[GetRight]`? Can you explain that part about converting links? I don't get that. What do you mean by that? Your file ID would normally sit after the `&id=`. Obviously you have removed it here for privacy. But are you saying you can't paste that URL in your browser and hit Enter to display it? Are you getting a 404 status error or something of that nature? You have to explain better what you're trying to do and how you're trying to do it.

Answer (score 7):

You can change a Google Drive image link to a download link by swapping for (just use a replace all tool, I'm fond of *TextMechanic's* simple, free, online *[Find and Replace](http://textmechanic.co/Find-and-Replace-Text.html)* but Notepad find and replace will do the trick).

I'm a user of Google Drive and as you say it's just a matter of getting the download link. An example on my drive is

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz697J8sF_ekS1ZSV0tGSS1ZbHc/edit?usp=sharing
```

for the share link, or

```
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bz697J8sF_ekS1ZSV0tGSS1ZbHc/edit
```

for the edit link. The download link is

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0Bz697J8sF_ekS1ZSV0tGSS1ZbHc
```

as described in [this article](http://lifehacker.com/share-direct-links-to-files-in-google-drive-and-skip-th-1493813665).

So it's simply a matter of find and replace on

`https://docs.google.com/file/d/` or `https://drive.google.com/file/d/`

for `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=`

and finding and replacing `/edit` or `/edit?usp=sharing` with   (nothing i.e. deleting them)

Once you've done that you can download a list of files in a number of ways, but if you want to stay in the browser I've written a Chrome extension called [*TabSave*](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-save/lkngoeaeclaebmpkgapchgjdbaekacki) to do just that - there's an option to use a manual list for downloading (it also allows downloading files in every tab of a window).

You can just paste in from your list of edited URLs and they'll download. Very lightweight and you don't need to worry about dodgy installation of these one-hit wonder freeware programs. All the code is open source on GitHub (link in the webstore description).

Comment: I changed this URL=https%3a%2f%2fdocs.google.com%2ffile%2fd%2f0B_y3Lfq-ziPxaFRneHVmMG44T3hzb2tTaFdDYW9xT3dneW8w%2fedit%3fusp%3ddrive_web to this https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B_y3Lfq-ziPxaFRneHVmMG44T3hzb2tTaFdDYW9xT3dneW8w/edit and use the Tabsave tool and I get download failed and 404 Error in browser view. What did I do wrong?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_y3Lfq-ziPxaFRneHVmMG44T3hzb2tT‌​aFdDYW9xT3dneW8w/edit?usp=drive_web gives me "*Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist.*". If navigating to the URL doesn't work then a browser extension won't do any better. You didn't delete the final `/edit` either: should be [https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B_y3Lfq-ziPxaFRneHVmMG44T3hzb2tT‌​aFdDYW9xT3dneW8w](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B_y3Lfq-ziPxaFRneHVmMG44T3hzb2tT‌​aFdDYW9xT3dneW8w)

Answer (score 2):

## Method 1

You can try a program called **URL Image Downloader**. It's a free software hosted on Source Forge. Here is a short description.

> You can download the images from a URL list. You only need a file with
>   URL list, and destination folder
>
> It is a console application, developed with .NET technology.

I have not tried this out myself, so I can't guarantee it will work. But I don't see any reason why it shouldn't. It seems like a very useful and simple to use tool.

[image: a]

The way it works is you create a plain text file containing the URLs for the photos you want to download, each URL on a new line. Something like this.

```
https://plus.google.com/photos/photo_01.jpg
https://plus.google.com/photos/photo_02.jpg
https://plus.google.com/photos/photo_03.jpg
https://plus.google.com/photos/photo_04.jpg
https://plus.google.com/photos/photo_05.jpg
https://plus.google.com/photos/photo_06.jpg
https://plus.google.com/photos/photo_07.jpg
https://plus.google.com/photos/photo_08.jpg
https://plus.google.com/photos/photo_09.jpg
https://plus.google.com/photos/photo_10.jpg
https://plus.google.com/photos/photo_11.jpg
https://plus.google.com/photos/photo_12.jpg
```

This is the hardest part, as you will have to do this work manually. You would then save this to `C:\Users\You\Desktop\Your_text_document.txt` for example. Once you have this file you would then use the tool to have it look for these file URLs online and grab them.

You can see in the example above from the screenshot how to type in your command. I recommend you to first prepare a folder (`/dest`) where you would want the downloaded files to be stored.

Link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/urlimagedownloader/

## Method 2

The second, and probably the easiest way to do this is to contact the person that sent you those photos. Ask them to move these photos into a new album, share it, and then have them send you the URL for the album.

- http://lmgtfy.com/?q=how+to+create+album+google+photos
- http://lmgtfy.com/?q=how+to+share+album+google+photos

Comment: It doesn't seem to like Google Drive's URL format.

Comment: The idea is very simple. You put your URLs in a text file, as a way of queuing them for a batch process. Then you execute the program and see the end result in your destination folder. You're probably doing it wrong somehow. If you are getting any errors, either in the browser or this program, let me know what you're seeing.

Comment: The problem is the links I have are in the following format: `https://docs.google.com/a/upr.edu/file/d/ID/edit?usp=drive_web`, where ID is the ID of the photo. They are not a direct link to the .jpg, but the Google Drive page itself.

Answer (score 0):

Open your own Google Drive.
Click on the links.
Download from your own Google Drive.
It's not the best solution, but it's better than 1-by-1 download/save.

Answer (score -1):

Install JDownloader free download manager. Copy the links (not link location) using ctrl + c JDownloder's link-grabber will automatically adds the links to download list form clipboard no need to edit the url.

Comment: Please exercise caution when recommending software. As written, your answer may be seen as spam. Your answer should include a description of the software and how it addresses the question. More information: [How do I recommend software in my answers?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5329)